# error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant

Tags: c

This is a part of my code.

```
#define BASE_ADDR       (0x41E00000)
#define UPPER_LIMIT         0X41E0FFFF
#define CONTROL_REG ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x60))
#define STATUS_REG ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x64))
#define DTR ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x68))
#define DRR (uint32_t *(BASE_ADDR+0x6C))
#define SLAVE_SEL ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x70))
```

And its giving an error on the BASE_ADDR define statement:

```
 spicode.c:11:21: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
 #define BASE_ADDR  (0x41E00000)
                     ^
```

Edit: There were errors in random places in my program because I did not place the brackets aroung uint32_t while defining DRR, putting these brackets removed the rest of the errors as well.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code? that cannot be the problem. The problem is somewhere, where you use that constant. As a rule of thumb, always put parens around #define constants.

Comment: The problem may caused by another part of your code where you used the `BASE_ADDR`.

Comment: yes i think you are right, the problem is somewhere else, i will post the rest of the code here

Comment: Why do you show us 2 different definitiones? Did you define `BASE_ADDR` twice?

Comment: `#define DRR (uint32_t *(BASE_ADDR+0x6C))` -> `#define DRR ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x6C))`

Comment: I have updated the question now.

Comment: @StoryTeller i am down the error, and now i have a new warning: can you help with this as well?

Comment: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint32_t’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("The data written in the FIFO is %p", *DRR);

Comment: There should be some additional `note` messages after this one that give more details of the error.

Comment: I'd think that's pretty obvious. `%p` is for printing pointer values, not integers (which is the lvalue you get from `*DRR`). How to print the stuff in `stdint.h` is a short google away from you.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code where you get thos warnings and errors. I don't think that "spicode.c:11:21" is what you show us. Line 11 would be `#define UPPER_LIMIT         0X41E0FFFF`

Comment: This fragment does not produce the error (on gcc at least). http://ideone.com/a1S6vI

Comment: @Persixty - Yeah the example is lacking. A problem with a macro will never be revealed if it isn't used.

Comment: The code still doesn't match the error message. This never was a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is at the definition of `DRR`.

Change it like the following:

```
#define DRR ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x6C))
```

---

In case like this the option `-E` can be very useful to see how the preprocessor is expanding the macros. In this case
using `clang -E` this is the output you get:

```
int main(){
 uint32_t* a= (uint32_t *(0x41E00000 +0x6C));
 return 0;
}
```

where the original source code is:

```
#define BASE_ADDR       0x41E00000
#define UPPER_LIMIT         0X41E0FFFF
#define CONTROL_REG ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x60))
#define STATUS_REG ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x64))
#define DTR ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x68))
#define DRR (uint32_t *(BASE_ADDR+0x6C))
#define SLAVE_SEL ((uint32_t *)(BASE_ADDR+0x70))


int main(){
    uint32_t* a= DRR;
    return 0;
}
```

It's pretty clear now why this code cannot compile.

`gcc` gives an informative message regarding the error:

```
test.c:10:25: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
 #define BASE_ADDR       0x41E00000
                         ^
test.c:15:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘BASE_ADDR’
 #define DRR (uint32_t *(BASE_ADDR+0x6C))
```

`clang` does a good job too:

```
test.c:20:15: error: expected ')'
        uint32_t* a= DRR;
                     ^
test.c:15:25: note: expanded from macro 'DRR'
#define DRR (uint32_t *(BASE_ADDR+0x6C))
```

Comment: Nice answer. But the question is due to a typo. Such are off-topic. It can very well be closed and removed eventually, making your effort for nothing,

Comment: The modern versions of GCC and Clang have dramatically improved the error reporting, as you show.  It's worth upgrading for that alone.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right.  icc (for instance)  error is a bit more vague: error: `expected an expression
   uint32_t* a= DRR;`